# ajaxuploader how to save file to different server

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

I'm searching for a way to upload file by ajax-uploader component or ASP:Fileupload to different server then the application is running on, is there a way ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It states

> "With .NET, you use the File class in the System.IO namespace to open the file. This returns a Stream object to which you can cast as a BinaryReader or BinaryWriter object. Using the BinaryReader object's ReadBytes method, you can obtain a byte array that you can use as the return value on the Web method."

you can find the code [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/create-a-simple-file-transfer-web-service-with-net/5805105)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it can be done directly, but we have had a similar problem with three-layer architecture. The file there came from client, via presentation layer to business layer where it was finally sent to database layer.

We solved it by opening a webservice call to the business layer and simply reading from input stream and writing to output stream until end of data. This way the middle server don't have to keep any considerable amount of data in memory while the file is being uploaded.